# Can Amazon AWS RDS MySQL databases be used in Azure?

Tags: mysql, azure, amazon-web-services, dbaas

We have mysql databases which we want to host on AWS RDS and want to use in Azure VM and web app. Both of them located in Singapore region.

Is this possible? If yes, How? What are pros and cons? And how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, build a Amazon VPC /Azure Network VPN tunnel by your own, with something like a cisco instance or linux vpn packages, or make your mysql amazon rds public accessible and set up  ssl encrypt connection to the db for more information see this doc

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html